# Defining two different partitions for home for different users

Tags: partitioning, permissions, login, 15.10

I have just installed 15.10 and I am trying to get 3 users established, two that will use one partition mounted as /home and the third to use a different partition mounted as `/home/cjowett`

Here is a partial output of mount:

```
/dev/sda8 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

/dev/sda9 on /home/cjowett type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

However after I define user cjowett the login for cjowett fails with no error popup or reason given.

When I initially created the user cjowett nothing got created in `/home/cjowett` so I tried deleting the user, copying all directories and files from one user to there and recreating the user but no difference.
What do I need to check to figure out why the user isn't being created correctly and why the login fails?

Comment: What do you mean by "the login fails"? Also, some screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: Who owns the mounted filesystem (`ls -ld /home/cjowett`)? Since it's a home dir, it will need to be owned by (and writable by) the user in question, I think

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to accomplish what I was trying to achieve:

I changed the mount point for `/dev/sda9` to `/aux` rather than `/home/cjowett`.

I defined user `cjowett` letting all files go to the normal spot on `/dev/sda8`
then a created a temporary link `/tmplnk` under `/home` pointing to `/aux`.

I moved everything:

```
mv /home/cjowett/* /tmplnk
```

then I deleted `/home/cjowett` and renamed the temporary link.

I had to change some ownership's and permissions along the way so steeldriver was onto something with his question above. It was likely ownership and permissions that was creating the problem in the first attempts.